# when to use !important property in css?

Tags: html, css

```
#div p {
    color: red !important;
}
...
#div p {
    color: blue;
}
```

I understand how !important works, in this case the div will render red because now it has priority (!important). But I can't still figure out an appropriate situation to use it. Does anybody know any example where !important saves the day?